# Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget anscestor

Tags: flutter, dart

(This is my first post so please excuse the poor format and mistakes)
I hope you all are doing great.
I am new to dart and programming, and I can't figuere out how to solve this.
[image]

.I have tried adding MaterialApp, which seems to be the solution everyone online is recommending but to no avail. please help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(home: ScaffoldExample())
);

class ScaffoldExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Scaffold",),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    ); // scaffold
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: can you remove `import 'User Interface/Scafold_Example.dart';` though it is not using there

Comment: Here are some method you can try, `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. If fails, try to upgrade the flutter in case you've overwritten the src code `flutter upgrade -f`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Thank you so much, flutter clean worked

flutter clean
clears cache, no? did that cause the problem? I apologize if I am being persistent, I am just trying to understand why the problem occurred.

Comment: It removes the build folder(build-cache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run these commands in terminals hope this will help you

```
>> flutter clean

>> flutter pub get
```

if this didn't worked try stopping and restarting the app. let me know if this help you or not.

Comment: flutter clean
solved it. Thanks a lot.